# MySQL: A bit complex query is returning count results wrong

Tags: mysql

There are these three tables:

```
posts
posts_replies
likes
```

This query is returning me data almost fine but for some reason the COUNT of Replies on Posts is not accurate.

```
SELECT posts.title, posts.num, posts.status, posts.category, posts.content, posts.member_num, COUNT( posts_replies.post_num ) AS count, COUNT( likes.comment_num ) AS likes_count
FROM posts_replies
INNER JOIN posts ON ( posts_replies.post_num = posts.num )
LEFT JOIN likes ON ( likes.comment_num = posts_replies.num )
WHERE posts.status =1
AND posts.access = 'Public'
GROUP BY posts.num
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 50
```

This is the count that i am using: **COUNT( posts_replies.post_num ) AS count**

Any advices on this?

Thank you

Comment: Is a post bound to have replies? If a post has no replies, then a LEFT JOIN on posts might make more sense.

Comment: @Gigi i tried **LEFT JOIN posts** instead of **INNER JOIN posts** but no affect.

Comment: example: a post has 7 comments but this query is returning 11 (**COUNT( posts_replies.post_num ) AS count**)

Comment: It might help to give us a sample of the data in these tables, and the result you are getting from the query, in order to be able to troubleshoot it better. Keep it simple though... maybe just a couple of entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will count each reply once for each like linked to that reply.

In order to count each reply just once, replace

```
COUNT( posts_replies.post_num ) AS count
```

with

```
COUNT(DISTINCT posts_replies.num ) AS count
```